# SQL ORDER BY next

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Please tell me how to sort in PostgreSQL (15+) such a table:

```
id |  name  | next_id
1  | Test01 |  2
2  | Test02 |  3
3  | Test03 |  6
4  | Test04 |  5
5  | Test05 |  null
6  | Test06 |  4
7  | Test07 |  null
```

It takes an SQL query to order by the next_id column - it's a pointer to the next row. The result I expect is:

```
id |  name  | next_id
1  | Test01 |  2
2  | Test02 |  3
3  | Test03 |  6
6  | Test06 |  4
4  | Test04 |  5
5  | Test05 |  null
7  | Test07 |  null
```

It is necessary to read the next_id field for each record, find this record and display it after the existing one. After all, this field can change, so sorting in ascending order will not work and other tricks.

So far, there are no ideas how to do it gracefully. Except for loops and temporary tables.

Comment: the problem is that you can't compare 2 arbitrary rows and find which comes first. (Also, why is row with id 1 at the top of your output?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following demonstrates an approach to sorting as requested:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id, name, next_id) AS (
  VALUES (1  , 'Test01',   2),
         (2  , 'Test02',   3),
         (3  , 'Test03',   6),
         (4  , 'Test04',   5),
         (5  , 'Test05',   NULL),
         (6  , 'Test06',   4),
         (7  , 'Test07',   NULL)),
cte AS (
  SELECT t.id, t.name, t.next_id, t.id AS root_id, 1 AS depth
    FROM t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t t2 WHERE t.id = t2.next_id)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.name, t.next_id, cte.root_id, cte.depth + 1 AS depth
    FROM t
    JOIN cte ON (t.id = cte.next_id))
SELECT cte.id, cte.name, cte.next_id
  FROM cte
 ORDER BY cte.root_id, cte.depth, cte.id;
```

This query assumes that there are no cycles in the path defined by `next_id`.

The query first initializes the recursive CTE by identifying the rows that are not referenced by any `next_id`, memoizing the root id, and initializing `depth`. The recursive portion of the CTE finds the rows referenced by these root rows and incrementing `depth`. The recursive part repeats using the rows discovered by the prior iteration until no rows are found.

The final step sorts by `root_id`, `depth`, and `id`. Including `id` in the sort is done to create a deterministic order for the case of `id`s with multiple `next_id`s (a tree structure instead of linear paths): it can be left out if only linear paths are allowed.